# main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file on override file: Solved

Tags: magento2.3

I want to override this file:

> /app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml

with this file:

> /app/design/frontend/Smartwave/foroutdoors/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml

This works fine on my staging server but on my live server the following message is displayed in /var/log/system.log:

> main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: '/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/foroutdoors/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Contact' block's name: 'contactForm'

This error message is displayed even if I put an unmodified version of form.phtml into the override folder.

What should I be looking at to correct this?

Comment: Check on your server if **/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/foroutdoors/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml** file exists. If not, run static content deploy command.

Comment: It did not exist. I ran the deploy command and all is now working. Excellent.

Comment: Glad to know it worked. Just remember whenever you face an issue with static files, try executing static content deploy command.